# How to work around SQL Server's "The maximum number of tables in a query (260) was exceeded."

Tags: sql-server-2000

i have a query that contains a series of 21 `UNIONs`, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown AS

   SELECT ... FROM a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM c
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM d
   ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM u
```

The query runs fine when run alone. But when the query is run through the containing view:

```
SELECT * FROM USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown 

Msg 4414, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not allocate ancillary table for view or function resolution. The maximum number of tables in a query (260) was exceeded.
```

i've tried splitting up my `USGovFedExpentiures` view into smaller chunks:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown AS

   SELECT x FROM TreasuryAuditResults
   UNION ALL
   SELECT x FROM USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Additions
   UNION ALL
   SELECT x FROM USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Subtractions
```

With `USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Additions` and `USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Subtractions` each containing roughly half the queries:

```
CREATE VIEW USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Additions AS
   SELECT ... FROM b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM c
   ...
   SELECT ... FROM k

CREATE VIEW USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Subtractions AS
   SELECT ... FROM l
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ... FROM m
   ...
   SELECT ... FROM u
```

But selecting from the "*parent*" view still fails:

```
SELECT * FROM USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown

Msg 4414, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not allocate ancillary table for view or function resolution. The maximum number of tables in a query (260) was exceeded.
```

How can i work around the 256 table limit?

### See also

- [FIX: A Transact-SQL query that uses views may fail unexpectedly in SQL Server 2000 SP3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828269)
- [MSDN: Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Comment: 1) Check for recursion (view reading from view reading from previous view). 2) Are all those a..u really just tables, or are any of them views?  You obviously don't have 260 tables in your query, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: Can you look at the query plan?

Comment: There was multiple joins to a view, which itself merges 3 tables. Things quickly multiplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague came up with a great answer. Use a function to return a table variable; insert the results into the table variable bit by bit:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown AS
    SELECT * FROM fn_USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown()
```

with the view now calling the UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown()
    RETURNS @Results TABLE
    (
        Total money, 
        ...
    )

    INSERT INTO @Results SELECT ... FROM a
    INSERT INTO @Results SELECT ... FROM b
    INSERT INTO @Results SELECT ... FROM c
    INSERT INTO @Results SELECT ... FROM d
      ...
    INSERT INTO @Results SELECT ... FROM u

    RETURN 
END
```

As far as any clients know the `view` is unchanged. (Except now it works!)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the subqueries into temp tables, e.g. the `USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Additions` and `USGovCurrencyOnHandBreakdown_Subtractions` that you mentioned, and than selecting from those temp tables instead of views.

Of course, the transactions could be an issue because of the dirty reads, I don't know if that's a concern in this case...