# Is there a way to run quick dummy SQL queries to test out aggregate functions, like so?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I realize this may be a really newbie question and I'm totally missin something ,  but I  want to test out using `MIN` with strings (in MSSQL):

```
MIN('d3d742ce-f12e-4402-9a0e-8a05066f6bed',
'03f8d7a7-9feb-4375-b7ff-04c187d46009',
'1c180a55-ce67-4ab4-afe5-9d9907ed1c21' )
```

But it tells me:

> Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 The MIN function requires 1
>   argument(s).

And that makes sense to me now, but I want to do something like that if possible.

Is there a way to do something like this, without using a specific table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's it: (Works starting from SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT min(id) 
FROM (
VALUES 
('d3d742ce-f12e-4402-9a0e-8a05066f6bed'),
('03f8d7a7-9feb-4375-b7ff-04c187d46009'),
('1c180a55-ce67-4ab4-afe5-9d9907ed1c21')) AS guids(id)
```

Answer (score 4):

What about just using a table variable

```
DECLARE @TABLE Table (str varchar(100))
INSERT @TABLE (str) VALUES ('d3d742ce-f12e-4402-9a0e-8a05066f6bed')
INSERT @TABLE (str) VALUES ('03f8d7a7-9feb-4375-b7ff-04c187d46009')
INSERT @TABLE (str) VALUES ('1c180a55-ce67-4ab4-afe5-9d9907ed1c21')

SELECT MIN(str) FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: Cool - This is  really helpful. But one thing -  I don't have write-access to this DB . Let me try anyway, thank you!!

Comment: +1, this is my preferred way of quickly working with test data, including when trying to answer questions here on SO.

Comment: +1 back, I was thinking about a derived table but also just throw table variables about often.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create your own derived table on the fly with unions:

```
select min(MyCol)
from (
    select 'd3d742ce-f12e-4402-9a0e-8a05066f6bed' as MyCol
    union all select '03f8d7a7-9feb-4375-b7ff-04c187d46009'
    union all select '1c180a55-ce67-4ab4-afe5-9d9907ed1c21'
) as MyDerivedTable
```

I'm using `union all` in this case because that's faster when you know your test data is all unique (it doesn't implicitly run as distinct like [`union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)).

This same technique can be used in a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;with CTE as (
    select 'd3d742ce-f12e-4402-9a0e-8a05066f6bed' as MyCol
    union all select '03f8d7a7-9feb-4375-b7ff-04c187d46009'
    union all select '1c180a55-ce67-4ab4-afe5-9d9907ed1c21'
)
select min(MyCol)
from CTE
```

I've begun the statement with a semi-colon because SQL Server will complain if you haven't terminated the previous statement with one.

This only works to a point, however, as you can only use 256 tables in a query before having to resort to [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915166/how-to-work-around-sql-servers-the-maximum-number-of-tables-in-a-query-260-w).